# how to dispose all hidden forms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am having a problem on memory loads of my app..
Since it uses `Dim f As New Form2` every time I want to view something, it adds up to the load. Though I cannot close it since I will not be able to use the form again, instead I hide it.
but I am not calling the `f` that I have hidden, instead I create another `f`..

from time to time.. if I open, and close, and open again, those `f`'s will be on the memory of a 24/7 application and that's a really heavy load I might say.

I have read about *garbage collection* and did some tests, and I think that *helps*, I guess.

here's the math of my app in the task manager :

Mainform -- 30mb --> then
I `Dim f As New Form2` and `Hide()` 20 `f`'s -- it became --> 57mb
after 5mins -- 50mb
this is where I *think* that GC occured.. or am I wrong.

that's about it explaining the current problem..
So, do I have an option like..

```
dim forms = application.hidden.ofType(form2)
'close em'
```

**OR**

```
'teach me some workaround, that would be great :)
```

**OR No Choice but**

```
'do nothing.. :/
```

Comment: Why can you not close the forms instead of hiding them? What are you doing with forms after you hide them?

Comment: I can't use form2 if I dispose it, all hidden forms are trash by then.

Comment: Are you using `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()` for these forms?

Comment: `.Show` .. I can't use modals coz I need them as I control `Form1` though `Form2.Owner = Form1`

Comment: how are the forms related to the Cameras?  Is the camera class really a form?

Comment: yup. here's the flow : Click Marker > New Instance > Load Camera > X > Hide... then again if user wants to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you dont want to restructure the code into a proper class, then the thing that creates form instances **must** be able to find the form/cams it creates so it can close them.  To do that it needs a) an identifier, b) a storage mechanism and c) a way to know the user is closing a form - you are missing at least 2 of those things.

a) an identifier

when mainform creates a form instance add something to the constructor like a name or tag.  This must be something the user cannot change.  This uses a GUID:

MainForm, probably a click event:

```
  Dim CamID As String = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
  Dim f as New Form2(CamID)
  ' more to come in a moment
```

Form2:

```
 Public CamGuid As String = ""

 ' modify **existing** Sub New adding a param
 Public Sub New(myCamID As String) 
   ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    CamGuid = myCamID
 End Sub
```

Now both the mainform and the camform have a common, unique identifier!

b) Storage

The Mainform needs to be able to find that `f` to close it properly:

```
  Private _cameras As New Dictionary(of String, Form2)
```

In that same click event, save the form ref just created:

```
  Dim CamID As String = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
  Dim f as New Form2(CamID)
  ' save form ref using CamID as a key
  _cameras.Add(CamID, f)
```

c)  Closing notice:
In form2 clos**ING** event:

```
   Me.Hide
   ' tell main form we are closing, identify which one using the camera GUID
   MainForm.CameraClosed(CamGuid)
```

Note: Put normal close code (like clean up and killing the camera feed) in CLOSE - we need a way for that to run normally.  So, put the HIDE and Call to MainForm in FormClosing.

In Main Form:

```
   Public Sub CameraClosed(cameraID As String)

        if _cameras.ContainsKey(cameraID) Then
            ' doing it the long way...fetch the form ref
            Dim f As Form2 = _cameras(CameraID)
            ' remove from dictionary of active forms
            _cameras.Remove(cameraID)
            f.Close            ' let normal CLOSE code run
            f = Nothing
        End if
   End Sub
```

Comment: If I use classes outside mainForm, I will recode all this. plus, I am not familiar in this type. can I just use `f= Nothing` on the closing event of form2?

Comment: anyway, I checked the question that you have answered for me. I have my code for that now. Load the markers from the DB at `Form_Load` my app is almost ready for deployment as of now, but the only problem is the big load that it will handle coz this will be probably open 24/7.. can I add `Finally` block `f=Nothing` to the code?

Comment: if the Form2 code knows about the instance variable (`f`) I suspect that is part of the problem - it shouldnt.  In the Form2 Close, dont do anything, other than what you might need to do to save cam settings or shut off the feed.  If they click 'X' for Cam3, let that form die on its own, GC will clean things up on its own.  the problem you have with that construction is that whatever created it (mainform?) now no longer knows that form instance is invalid!  As a **hack**, you could add code for each `f` to tell Mainform that the `MallCam` is closing so it knows that `f` is dead.

Comment: @AdorableVB changed answer to reflect a mechanism for MainForm to know who is closing and then properly close them

Comment: I am on step C.. I don't get what you mean in there. the `OnClick` event code is on `MainMap_OnMarkerClick`

Comment: we (you) do not want the form to close when the user clicks close - we want to let MainForm close and dispose of it.  So in the CameraForm's **FormClosing** event (not FormClosed - its too late then), Hide and then tell main form to close it.  Since MainForm created the form, he cleans up including removing the entry for the camera/form and the form reference.  The last step is how MainForm knows whether to create a new Form or not when the user clicks.

Comment: first open of app - 31mb ---- open 9 cams - 51mb ---- close 9 cams - 46mb ---- I guess there are still some redundancy, will GC clean that? or will it stay like that (46mb)?

Comment: GC doesnt happen instantly, and you still have to make sure any resources you allocate are freed.  you might want to check `Application.OpenForms` before and after a close to make sure they are closed/gone - if you have something **else** referencing them, they wont go away.  40-50 MB is not much, check after 8 or 9 hours of regular use to see what it is.